# Extension method for IEnumerable<T> which returns type of -this-

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Like I see, most IEnumerable extensions eats IEnumerable and then vomits also IEnumerable. Is it possible to make an extension method, which can eat any IEnumerable (like List) and then return the same type - List?

For example, I want to iterate over collection, if something is wrong, I will throw exception, but if all is OK, I need to return same instance (same type).

Comment: Note that what you propose implies consuming the `IEnumerable`, so you lose the on-demand (lazy) iteration and side-effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how doing this could be beneficial, but you can solve the generics part of the problem like this:

```
public static TEnumerable MyExtensionMethod<T, TEnumerable>(this TEnumerable enumerable)
    where TEnumerable : IEnumerable<T>
{
    ...
}
```

However, you may find it difficult to actually implement such a thing because there is no generic way to create the `TEnumerable` you want to return.

> For example, I want to iterate over collection, if something is wrong, I will throw exception, but if all is OK, I need to return same instance (same type).

Does the following extension method not accomplish what you really want?  I don't understand why you want to return the same instance.

```
public static void Consume<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
{
    foreach (var item in enumerable)
    {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: He's always going to be returning the argument provided, according to his question.

Comment: Returning the source sequence allows this, or other sequence operations, to be chained, without forcing local variables to be created.

Comment: So to call it, I'm forced to use list.MyExtensionMethod<int, List<int> (); ??? Then .Cast<List<int>(); is nearly same length.

Comment: @zgnilec Yes, as I stated in my answer.  That is, unless you also provide an argument of type `T` or that uses `T` as a generic argument.

Comment: @Servy Yes I of course understood that was the intention. My point was that it doesn't seem like a thing that's appropriate to chain.  "For example, I want to iterate over collection, if something is wrong, I will throw exception, but if all is OK, I need to return same instance (same type)."  `Select`, `Where`, etc. already do this - they throw if the collection being enumerated has a problem.  So why the extra extension method unless it is meant to be done standalone (not within a chain of calls)?

Comment: @TimothyShields Presumably he has other methods to call that return "itself", i.e. builder objects.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use two generic arguments:

```
public static TEnumerable Foo<TEnumerable, TItem>(this TEnumerable sequence)
    where TEnumerable: IEnumerable<TItem>
{
    return sequence;
}
```

Note that as a result of this change you're not going to be able to infer the generic arguments when invoking this method; you're going to have to specify them explicitly.